# Lance Pong example not working in browser: 'bundle.js' missing

Tags: javascript, pong, lance

I hope everyone is safe and well. I followed the `Lance Pong tutorial`, all went well, server is running on `3000` on an ubuntu server with apache with ProxyPass enabled, and happily reporting players 1 and 2 are battling it out.

But visiting the site in a web browser shows the static black div with white paddle that won't move.

The console reports error:
`"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 (Proxy Error)"` for the file 'bundle.js'

I'm sure it is my ignorance of `Babel` or `WebPack` or `Node` or `npm` or all the things, but if somebody could help, I'd most appreciate it.

B-30

edit: getting same error with Spaaace tutorial too, so suspect it is something either to do with my server setup or package versions?